# What's difference between callSuper and callParent in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

What's difference between callSuper and callParent ?

My Example :

```
Ext.define('Ext.some.Class', {

    method: function () {
        console.log('Good');
    }
});

Ext.define('Ext.some.DerivedClass', {
  extend: 'Ext.some.Class',
    method: function () {
        console.log('Bad');
        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.define('App.paches.DerivedClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.some.DerivedClass',

    method: function () {
        console.log('Fixed');
        this.callSuper();
    }
}); 
var object = Ext.create('App.paches.DerivedClass');  
object.method();
```

Help me .
I'll be glad to any comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8sg) to demonstrate that
(switch between callSuper and callParent in the overridden class to see the difference in console logs)

Based on this [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callSuper).